# How to run selected feature files/scenarios in cypress cucumber and skip others

Tags: cucumber, cypress

I tried several commands but nothing seems to work. Either it escapes all or runs none.

```
@TestFeature
Feature: Test Feature

    Testing sample feature

    Background: Logging in
    @manual
    Scenario: A
        Given
    Scenario Outline: B
```

I want to run `Test Feature` and skip the scenarios marked `manual`. I tried -

```
npx cypress run --env TAGS=@TestFeature and not @manual --browser chrome
```

But it doesn't work. Also tried similar combinations, but none work.

Answer (score 5):

You can run specific test-files or features using the [CLI option `--spec` (short: `-s`)](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/command-line#cypress-run-spec-lt-spec-gt) like:

```bash
npx cypress run --spec cypress/integration/TestCases/Testsite.feature --env \"TAGS=@smoke\" --browser chrome",
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 4):

You are able to use @tags in Feature Files and get Cypress to run selected tests only. You need to be careful to escape inverted commas.  The following worked for me (running tests tagged with @accessibility tag):

**package.json**

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "cypress:open": "cypress open",
    "cypress:run": "cypress run",
    "test:accessibility": "./node_modules/.bin/cypress-tags run -e TAGS=\"@accessibility\"",
    "test": "cypress run --spec \"**/*.feature\"",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

Then at the command prompt:

```
cypress-tags run -e TAGS="@accessibility"
```

Comment: when I run one scenario using tag @smoke it works but at the same time, other scenarios are marked as skipped. Is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: what the heck is an "inverted comma"?

Comment: aka "speech marks" https://www.bbc.co.uk/bitesize/topics/zvwwxnb/articles/ztcp97h

Comment: No link beetween package.json and the cmd ! 
see => https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/v/4.3.1#cucumber-functions

Answer (score 3):

You can use the @focus tag. See https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

```
@focus
Scenario: Opening a search engine page
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know it isn't currently not possible to run tests with a tag. You could create an issue for this in github ( https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues ) to let them implement it.

As a work around we choose to create smoketests and featuretests. The smoketests are in a seperate directory which enables us to only run those test scenario's in stead of the whole test suite. You can do so by running the tests with this command:
`npx cypress run --spec /cypress/smoketest/*`

Comment: I doesn't seem to run feature files this way. May be only specs.