# How to Run Specific Scenario in Cypress Test Runner

Tags: typescript, cucumber, cypress

I am working with Cypress,TypeScript,Cypress-Cucumber-Pre-Processor Framework.

Cypress Test Runner is a great tool to debug and check everything that is happening with your test case , but every time I select a spec file(**In my case Feature File**) to run , all the test cases
are invoked to run

I want to run specific test case here ,I know command line method to run specific test case with tags,
But I want to run it using Cypress Test Runner , Is there any way ?

Comment: you want to check out this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58872387/how-to-run-selected-feature-files-scenarios-in-cypress-cucumber-and-skip-others

Comment: I am aware of this way to run specific test case using tag , But this will only work when u invoke via command line npx cypress run -e TAGS=\"@test\"  not with Cypress Test Runner(I am looking for a solution to run selected test case in Cypress Test Runner)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe instead of using a special dev feature, you want to use `@only` tag.

See [cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/features/tags
/only_tag.feature](https://github.com/badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/blob/v17.2.1/features/tags/only_tag.feature) is an example of this option.

```js
  Rules:
   - In presence of any @only tag, only tests tagged with this should be run
   - This behavior is scoped per file
   - Presence of this tag override any other tag filter
```

If you look further at the example, you can see it added to Feature or to Scenario.

This part shows temporary application of `@only` working to run only that tagged scenario, even though another tag is specified in the permanent configuration.

```js
  Scenario: specifying tags
    Given a file named "cypress/e2e/a.feature" with:
      """
      Feature: a feature
        @only
        Scenario: a scenario
          Given a step

        @foo
        Scenario: another scenario
          Given a step
      """
    And a file named "cypress/support/step_definitions/steps.js" with:
      """
      const { Given } = require("@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor");
      Given("a step", function(table) {});
      """
    When I run cypress with "-e tags=@foo"
    Then it should appear to have run the scenario "a scenario"
    And it should appear to have skipped the scenario "another scenario"
```

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, I created DevelopFeature , This feature file will only contain the test case I am developing so that I can run only this single Test Case in Cypress Test Run
Once Development of Test Case is completed,I am moving this scenario to desired feature